# PHP Excel Writer Wrap text

Tags: php, spreadsheet-excel-writer

I'm using this plugin, I know it's not the best, but I don't have time to rewrite all these scripts. I need to know how enable text wrap. The [incomplete documentation](http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.fileformats.spreadsheet-excel-writer.spreadsheet-excel-writer-format.settextwrap.php) on the website doesn't help at all.

I have tried using 1 and 'wrap' as the parameter in the array, but no luck.

Has anyone gotten this to work?

Comment: Does your cell contain contain actual line breaks ("\n") or are you simply expecting it to wrap on white space? BTW, setTextWrap() doesn't take any arguments

Comment: No it doesn't contain line breaks.

Comment: And it has to take arguments, because how will it know where the text wrap is required?

Comment: If you look at the actual documentation for enabling word wrap, it doesn't take an argument. Word wrap is a boolean state (true or false) for a format, and setTextWrap() always sets it to TRUE... you can pass an argument, and it will simply be discarded.

Comment: I see what you mean. As shown in the answer, I approached it the wrong way! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok figured it out. I was trying to do it like this:

```
$format_caption =& $workbook->addFormat(array('size' => 11, 'fontFamily' => 'Calibri', 'numformat' => '@', 'bold' => 1, 'left' => 1, 'top' => 1, 'bottom' => 1, 'right' => 1, 'vAlign' => 'vcenter', 'align' => 'center', 'fgcolor' => 50, 'textWrap' => 1));
```

But setting `'textWrap' => 1` didn't work.

So I changed it a bit:

```
$format_caption =& $workbook->addFormat(array('size' => 11, 'fontFamily' => 'Calibri', 'numformat' => '@', 'bold' => 1, 'left' => 1, 'top' => 1, 'bottom' => 1, 'right' => 1, 'vAlign' => 'vcenter', 'align' => 'center', 'fgcolor' => 50));
$format_caption -> setTextWrap();
```

And that solved my issue.

Answer (score 7):

If You want to use construction addFormat(), name of wrapText property have to be 'wrap'.

You wrote: *'textWrap' => 1*

you should: *'wrap' => true or 'wrap' => 1*

for example:

```
$style = array(
    'alignment' => array(
        'horizontal' => PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_CENTER,
        'wrap' => true
    )
);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($style);
```

the result for cell **A1** is central alignment whith text wraping

Comment: With the latest version of PHPExcel it's actually [`'textWrap' => true`](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/9fdcaabe3cfe49e736e8e92a6700a756776407df/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Style/Alignment.php#L57)

Answer (score 1):

This code worked for me in PhpSpreadsheet

```
 $styleArray = [
            'borders'   => [
                'allBorders' => [
                    'borderStyle' => Border::BORDER_THIN,
                ],
            ],
            'alignment' => [
                'wrapText' => true,
            ],
        ];

 $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'product_name')->getStyle('A1')->applyFromArray($styleArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

textWrap not working bacause you set ROW height, ex:

```
$worksheet -> setRow($numRow, 17);
```

Remove this line, and height of row will be calculating automaticly.